# How can I populate a user_id param using current_user id if Author and user_id from dropdown if not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan

I am trying to populate a user_id param from being an Author. What I want to do is basically if you are a logged in user with role author and you create a book I want it to use your logged in id to populate that user_id param, if you are logged in as an Admin user you can create a book but use a select list of users/authors to add to the book.

Here is what I have got:

BooksController

```
def create
    # raise params.inspect
    @book = Book.create(book_params)
    if current_user.role_id == '2'
      @book.user_id = current_user.id
    else
      @book.user_id = params[:user_id]
    end

    #binding.pry

    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.save
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @book }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def update
    @book.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @book.update(book_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @book.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Then in my form view I have this setup:

```
<% if current_user.role.name == "Author" %>
      <div id="author" class="field">
        <!-- <h3>Hey <%= current_user.name %> your signed in as an <%= current_user.role.name %></h3> -->
      </div>
    <% elsif %>
      <div id="author" class="field">
        <h3>Select author of book</h3>
        <%#= debug Book.book_authors %>

        <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.order(:name),:id,:name, {:include_blank => false} %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

All I want to do is enable Authors to create/update books with their logged in data to populate the param user_id and Admins to create/update books by using a dropdown instead to populate the param user_id.

Comment: What is your problem, what does not work?

Comment: It's not populating the user_id param

Comment: I would expect the `user_id` in `params[:book][:user_id]` not just `params[:user_id]`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that too but it still did not populate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do too much at once. Simplify the problem and get small bits working. For example you are using @book in your update controller without defining it first. As another example, you refer to role_id (int) in your create controller. Your form refers to role.name (string).

Get the controllers working first, then add your feature.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems/solutions:

1)

```
if current_user.role_id == '2'
```

I'm assuming you have a Role model and a user has_one :role association. If that's the case you shouldn't use '2' but 2 without single quotes. A foreign_key is not a string but an integer. If you don´t have such a model/association, then, you cannot use user.role.name later.

2) When you use Book.create(book_params) you not only instanciate a book but save it (if valid) to the DB. Can you create a Book without an user_id? If not, you have a mistake right there, because you are trying to create that book before assigning the author (when the Author is the one filling the form she is not passing an user_id when submitting).

3) The main suspect is your book_params. Check the server log to see if you are passing the user_id params but it's being blocked as unpermitted. Check that you are including :user_id in yours params....permit(:user_id)

Other comments:

a) I would suggest you replace the Book.create for Book.new. But if you keep the book.create, the following is not needed:

```
...
else
  @book.user_id = params[:user_id]
end
```

(You already created the book with that user ID. Also it should be params[:book][:user_id]

b) As Matt said, if you are not setting @book with a before_action in update, you have another problem there.